# How to open base64 spreadsheet on Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, base64, spreadsheet, xls

I've been trying to manipulate a file that's base64 encoded that I'm recieving from my client.

I'm currently using  https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet/blob/master/GUIDE.md to manipulate it, however, there doesn't appear to be any way to open a file directly from the base64 blob, or should I write it and then read from it? can't that a potential security threat for the server?

for example, if I recieve a file :

```
file = params[:file] with contents:

data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,0M8R4KGxGuEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAOwADAP7
```

(should I remove the data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64, ?)

I'd like to open it with this:

```
Spreadsheet.client_encoding = 'UTF-8'
book = Spreadsheet.open "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/spreadsheet/event.xls"
```

(or with a blob or temp fle)

Sorry if it's pretty obvious, been looking for hours and there's not much info about it available, tried creating a temp file first but I don't think that's supported and there's not much I can get from the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shot in the dark: Maybe decode it, write to binary-enabled tempfile, and then feed that to `Spreadsheet`?

```
tmpfile = Tempfile.new.binmode
tmpfile << Base64.decode64(params[:file])
tmpfile.rewind
book = Spreadsheet.open(tmpfile)
```